# Need htaccess rewrite to remove id part

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, directory

I am looking for a rewrite rule to the same url's without the "#-" The # is the article ID, so it changes with each particular article. Categoryname also changes.

```
www.site.com/foldername/categoryname/45-article<br>
www.site.com/foldername/categoryname/334-article<br>
www.site.com/foldername/anothercategoryname/634-article
```

I used...

```
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[\d]*-(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

This works great on all foldernames and it's categories, but my problem is that i need it to work **only** on certain foldernames and each catagory within that foldername. So i am hoping there is a rule simlilar to the one i used, but where i specify particular foldernames. Thank you for any help on this matter.

Comment: Well, don't do a match against `.*` then.  Match against string literals, e.g. the folder names.  What *are* the category names, and are they static/finite?

Comment: Example of a folder name is chevy. Categories within that foldername would be impala, malibu, corvette. Chevy for example would have 10 catagories, but foldername Buick would only have 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match against the folder names.  You don't provide any, I'll say you want to match folders foo, bar, and baz only:

```
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar|baz)/([^\/]+)/[\d]+-(.+)$ /$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
                  ^^^        ^^^    ^^^^^^
                   1          2        3
```

Here you:

1. match first against the folder subset you want to match
2. then you match any category within those folders
3. then you remove the numbers

Minor nitpick: when you *know* your expression will match characters (for example, after the dash in your article names) it's nice to use `.+` instead of `.*`.  The latter will match zero characters, my guess is that that isn't a valid use case, so best not to allow it.